# DCAT Input Support in CKAN via Plugin

Tags: ckan, dcat

I'm working on a project that requires integrating DCAT-formatted data into a CKAN instance. We need an efficient way to support this, ideally through the UI, where users can easily upload or input their DCAT data.

I'm exploring the option to build a CKAN plugin that allows users to upload DCAT-formatted data through the UI. The plugin would convert this DCAT data into CKAN-friendly format behind the scenes.. Are there existing solutions or plugins for this? and Any best practices or potential pitfalls to consider?

I havent tried anything yet. This question is more of a recommendation and suggestions for an upcoming project